# GC overhead limit exceeded trying to build LibGDX project

Tags: java, android, robovm

I'm trying to run a LibGDX project with the iOS configuration but I keep running into the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ios:launchIPhoneSimulator'.
> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I've tried modifying the gradlew file with the following params, but I still get the same error:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Xmx2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
```

Any ideas what else I can do to work around this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tried several different things (gradlew clean, removing the dependencies and downloading them again, increasing heap size all the way to 2g, etc), but eventually what fixed it was rebooting the machine.

Yeah, a reboot fixed it. Weird.

Comment: This also fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... but I was found the solution!
Open your "gradle.properties" file and it must be something like this:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx512m
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

You must to edit the second string! Change "-Xms128m" to "-Xms1024m", "-Xmx512m" to "-Xmx4096m" and "gradle.properties" in final must look like:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this error by adding next flag: -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
. But it's bad approach.

This exception occur then FULL GC worked to often last minute and didn't free any memory(or free too low memory).

You can try to add additional memory, for example try to add -Xmx3048m (or more). If exception will still occur then definitely there is a memory leak problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change your code, but you suddenly have this problem, my suggestion is restart android studio, clean project, reboot your emulator. If not, then change the code of build.gradle.